# C#: Comparing with null

Tags: c#, null

Are these equivalent:

```
if (null==myobject)
{
//do something 
}
```

and

```
if (myobject==null)
{
//do something 
}
```

or will they produce different code?

Comment: First one is also known as Yoda condtion :)

Answer (score 41):

In the 99% case this code is equivalent.

The one exception is when the type of the object in question overrides the == operator.  It's possible for a bug to be introduced in == which causes problems when one parameter is null.

A particular example I've seen before is the following

```
public static bool operator==(Student left, Student right) {
  return left.Equals(right);
}
```

This will fail when null is on the left, but likely not when null in on the right.

This is a pretty far out corner case though.

Comment: The solution is: `if((object)left == null)` or `if(ReferenceEquals(left, null))`. The former is perhaps more performant.

Comment: @Justice, I haven't ever investigated the JIT but if you do Object.Reference equals, C# will generate a method call.  In the abscence of a operator== C# will generate a direct value comparison with the IL opcode ceq.  My guess is the ceq is faster.

Comment: @Justice, but don't ever assume anything about performance, trust the profiler :)

Comment: To be clear: this does not mean that one comparison is more correct than the other. The bug can be introduced both ways. The operator can be rewritten as `return right.Equals(left);` and then the code will crash if the `right` student is `null` (`myobject == null`).

Comment: Both `null == student` and `student == null` will still invoke the overridden `==` operator, regardless of the operand order. So this answer looks wrong to me.

Comment: yeah @DmytroShevchenko is right. this is b/s answer..

Answer (score 9):

The form of "`if`" statement that puts the constant at the left is a holdover from C/C++ where you could have an arbitrary expression in an if statement.

C#'s syntax for if statements requires that the expression evaluate to a bool which means that `if (foo = 0)` won't compile.

Comment: Oh good. I was remembering back a couple of years ago, when I was learning C#, and I'd sworn I recalled getting a compiler warning or error when using assignment (by accident) in an if statement, along with other safety devices (such as a missing break in a switch statement). +1

Comment: We used to do that deliberately, to make an assignment and check the value at the same time. The assignment operator in C++ returns the assigned value. I kinda miss that feature, but it was easy to abuse.

Comment: @Jasmine: I sometimes use the construct as well - you just do "if ((foo = bar()) == nullptr)".  But usually that doesn't survive code review - it gets changed to "foo = bar(); if (foo == nullptr)" which is cleaner IMHO.

Comment: Yes I agree. If you're always going to do the assignment, might as well put it on a separate line. It probably compiles that way anyway.

Comment: There's still the risk of accidental assignment when you have a bool involved in a comparison, which is fairly rare but exists: `if (wasEnabled == isEnabled()) ...`

Answer (score 8):

The

```
if (null==myobject) {
```

is a safe way of writing an if statement. It comes from C/C++ where the condition is an expression evaluated to an `int`. If the result is zero that means `false`, anything else is `true`. You could write something like

```
if (variable == 1) {
```

but if you weren’t careful you could also write

```
if (variable = 1) {
```

in which case you have an assignment that always evaluates to 1 and thus is always true.

You could compile this and run it with no problems, but the result wouldn’t be what you expected. So C/C++ programmers started to write things like

```
if (1 == variable) {
```

This won’t compile if you misspell it, so you always had to write it as you meant to write it. This later becomes a (good) habit and you use it in all the languages you program with, C# for example.

Comment: By misspell, you mean mistype. Saying misspell is misleading.
But you're the only one that has made this very good point.

Answer (score 3):

For those who miss it, of if you're looking to reduce clutter, it's also possible to enable `C-language`-style null-checking for your `C#` classes:

```
class MyObj
{
    public void implicit_null_comparison_demo()
    {
        MyObj mo = null;
        // ...

        if (mo)         //  <-- like so (can also use !mo)
        {
            // it's not null...
        }
        else
        {
            // it's null...
        }
    }

    public static implicit operator bool(MyObj mo)
    {
        return (Object)mo != null;
    }
};
```

Comment: Nice. What are the dangers of doing this?

Comment: Mainly, you'll miss the entire class of errors where assignment `=` is mistakenly used instead of equality testing `==`, which **C#**--unlike **C** and **C++**--normally flags as a syntax error.

Comment: Exactly. It can be a hard bug to see since the difference is just a single character and because of the visual similarity, so it used to be (still is?) a common complaint about **C**.

Comment: I guess some linters would be able to catch it, but it's no longer a syntax error.

Comment: @PeterWood Maybe, but I don't think **C#** developers have developed a very robust 'lint' tradition, due to both (1.) the original, fundamental language design philosophy having learned from past bad experiences to avoid the very types of problem we're discussing here, and also (2.) the IDE live-editing experience being so rich.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by others they are mostly equivalent.

You should also take a look at:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern

It is a very useful alternative to simply checking for a null reference.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you overload ==, both cases produce the same results.